# Break point in runtime class not working during Android application debug

Tags: android, android-studio, breakpoints

I created a new Android application on Win10x64 with Android Studio 3.5.1 and set a breakpoint in onCreate of the MainActivity which breaks successfully.

In the call stack there are many methods in the Android runtime such as ZygoteInit#main and ActivityThread#main, but breakpoints in these functions don't hit, why? The breakpoint has a red filled circle with a checkmark on it which is the same icon as the breakpoint in the MainActivity.

Note: I can open source file of these runtime classes with clicking in the call stack which is in AndroidSDK\sources\android-28. But when opening these files, there are a lot of errors in the source editor but I don't think this matters.

[image: Screen Shot]

Comment: can you show a screenshot of your code